# Asp .Net Word Automation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ms-word

We have a situation where we have to

1. Open up a Word document(template)
2. Get data from DB and merge it to that document
3. **Give the users ability to add or modify sections in that merged document**
4. finally save the document (which needs to go back to the DB)

I know that atleast the first two is possible. But is it possible for 3 to happen through a web site?

Any ideas or information or third party tools to accomplish this is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Raja

Answer (score 3):

THe Aspose component is pretty good for being able to manipulate docs through an API:
http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx

Alternatively if you are using the docx file formats you can read up on the Office OpenXML format and make the changes directly to the file.

Comment: Thanks for the info DevAngel. I did look at aspose but could not find option to satisfy requirement # 3 (Give users ability to add or modify sections in that merged document) :(.

Comment: Did you look at the Document Builder functionality? http://www.aspose.com/demos/.net-components/aspose.words/csharp/general/document-builder.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In general, [you should avoid automating Office from server-side apps](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757).

A better approach is to [use OOXML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML).

You can use the packaging APIs to produce a word file, or... you can produce the "template" .docx file in Word 2007/2010, then in the ASPNET app, open the .docx with a zip library like DotNetZip, modify the portion you need to modify (it's an XML doc) then re-zip and you have a valid .docx file.